# Regex in syslog template

Tags: regex, syslog

I try to use regex in a syslog template but it still not works. I first tried do match everthing to see if it works but it dont works. I tested my expression with a online tool and there it works. In my opinion the log message should be empty because the expression always match or? But there are always zeros in the log file.

```
template(name="testLogFormat" type="list")
   property(name="syslogtag"
            regex.type="ERE"
            regex.submatch="0"
            regex.expression=".*--end"
            regex.nomatchmode="ZERO"
)
```

Comment: How should it work? What is the sample input and what is expected output? Your current regex does not find any matches and `regex.nomatchmode="ZERO"` settings  outputs `0`s. If you want blanks upon no match, use `regex.nomatchmode="BLANK"`

Comment: I hace a string abc[123] and i want to get the term inside the bracket or if it is empty i want 0. With .* i match every charakter or?!

Comment: Try `regex.expression="\[([0-9]+)]"` and `regex.submatch="1"`

Comment: Thanks but i tried this before and i got an error when i restart syslog with this template. "syslogd: run failed with error -2207" syslog Version 7.4.7.

Comment: Did you add it like `%msg:R,ERE,1,ZERO:\[([0-9]+)]--end%`? Rsyuslog.com says: "A very simplistic example of how to use this expression inside rsyslog.conf is given below: `$Template tpl,"%msg:R,ERE,1,ZERO:\[([0-9]+)]--end%\n"` <line break> `*.*      /path/to/file;tpl`"

Comment: I added it as list but i tried it before also as string

Comment: Well, I don't see any issue with my regex, it is POSIX ERE compatible. Either the newlines are to blame, or the issue is out there.

Comment: I found that the \[ is used as a special character and i have to use \\[ that it works.

Comment: My main Problem is not to seperate the number. I need to log the number always with four digits also when the number is lower than 1000. So i need to insert a leading 0 when the number is shorter than 4 digits. Is there any easy solution?!

Comment: The regex is used here to *extract* the *existing* tex. If you can pipe the results to some string manipulation feature, then adding arbitrary text to matches would be possible.If you need to make sure the number consists of less than 4 digits inside the square brackets, just replace `+` with `{1,3}` => `regex.expression="\[([0-9]{1,3})]"`. If you need to make sure there is some specific text before `=`, add it => `regex.expression="text\[([0-9]{1,3})]"`

Comment: I updated the comment: to match numbers from `0` to `999` you may use `[0-9]{1,3}`. If you want to disallow `0`, you may use `([1-9][0-9]{0,2})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string looks like `abc[123]`. So, you may fix your current config using

```
regex.submatch="1"
regex.expression="\[([0-9]+)]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAVSQG/1).

Here,

- `\[` - matches  a `[`
- `([0-9]+)` - captures into Group 1 (you access the value using `regex.submatch="1"`)
- `]` - a closing `]`.